# Group rows in html data based on json data's value. And expand row when tapped on each value showing details

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON data as follows:

```
{
"data": [{
    "appDetails": [{
        "appDescription": [{
                "appName": "App X",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.25",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            },
            {
                "appName": "App X",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            },
            {
                "appName": "App X",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.23",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            },
            {
                "appName": "App Y",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.1",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            },
            {
                "appName": "App Y",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.2",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            },
            {
                "appName": "App Z",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.0",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            },
            {
                "appName": "App Z",
                "timeStamp": "",
                "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.1",
                "blocker": "3",
                "critical": "4",
                "major": "30",
                "minor": "2",
                "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
                "FailedTests": "0",
                "CodeCoverage": "90"
            }
        ]
    }]
}]}
```

My angular js code is about `http.get` method to fetch the above json from cloudant database and use `$scope` to push the data on the html table. 
Angular js code:

```
  function DashboardTablesPageCtrl($scope,$http,$timeout) {


$scope.tableData = [];
$scope.myFilter = ""

  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://'+ACCOUNTNAME+'.cloudant.com/_session',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: 'name='+APIKEY+'&password='+APIPASSWORD,
    withCredentials: true
  }


 $http(req).then(function(result){
        //Grab data
        req = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://'+ACCOUNTNAME+'.cloudant.com/'+DATABASE+'/_all_docs',
          withCredentials: true
        }
        var i = 0;

        $timeout(function(){
        $http(req).then(function(result){
            for(i=0;i<result.data.total_rows;i++){
                var id = result.data.rows[i].id

                $http.get('https://'+ACCOUNTNAME+'.cloudant.com/'+DATABASE+'/'+id).then(function(data){
                    var data = data.data

                        angular.forEach(data.data[0].appDetails, function(appDetail, index) {
                        angular.forEach(appDetail.appDescription, function(appDescription, index){
                            $scope.tableData.push(appDescription);

                        });
                    });

                })

    }       
  },
  function(){
    console.log("Failed at grabbing data");
  });
}, 
function(){
  console.log('Failed at authenticating');
});

});}})();
```

I have used ng-repeat in my html tablebody to display the data as below:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: myFilter ">
  <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
  <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
  <td>{{item.blocker}}</td>
  <td>{{item.critical}}</td>
  <td>{{item.major}}</td>
  <td>{{item.minor}}</td>
  <td>{{item.UnitTestsTotal}}</td>
  <td>{{item.FailedTests}}</td>
  <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>      
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This displays all the data in different rows. I need all the data of App X, App Y and App Z to be grouped and only three rows shown and click of App X should show up the data of App X by expanding the rows in the same table.

I am unable to achieve this as I am getting only different rows for each data on the table. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is to show and hide rows for given app name when user clicks on row with app name.
It can be achieved by having rows with app names only (to click on them) and rows filtered by app names:

```
  <tr><td colspan="10" ng-click=swapExpandingX()>App X</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="expandX" ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: { appName: 'App X'}">
    <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
    ...
    <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr><td colspan="10" ng-click=swapExpandingY()>App Y</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="expandY" ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: { appName: 'App Y'}">
    <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
    ...
    <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>
  </tr>
```

And swap functions in controller called on click:

```
  $scope.expandX = false;

  $scope.swapExpandingX = function() {
      $scope.expandX = !$scope.expandX;
  }
```

See how it works in snippet below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.expandX = false;
  $scope.expandY = false;

  $scope.swapExpandingX = function() {
      $scope.expandX = !$scope.expandX;
  }
  
  $scope.swapExpandingY = function() {
      $scope.expandY = !$scope.expandY;
  }

  $scope.tableData = [{
      "appName": "App X",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.25",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App X",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App X",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.23",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Y",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.1",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Y",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.2",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Z",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.0",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Z",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.1",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td colspan="10" ng-click=swapExpandingX()>App X</td></tr>
      <tr ng-show="expandX" ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: { appName: 'App X'}">
        <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
        <td>{{item.blocker}}</td>
        <td>{{item.critical}}</td>
        <td>{{item.major}}</td>
        <td>{{item.minor}}</td>
        <td>{{item.UnitTestsTotal}}</td>
        <td>{{item.FailedTests}}</td>
        <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr><td colspan="10" ng-click=swapExpandingY()>App Y</td></tr>
      <tr ng-show="expandY" ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: { appName: 'App Y'}">
        <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
        <td>{{item.blocker}}</td>
        <td>{{item.critical}}</td>
        <td>{{item.major}}</td>
        <td>{{item.minor}}</td>
        <td>{{item.UnitTestsTotal}}</td>
        <td>{{item.FailedTests}}</td>
        <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Removing code repetitions**

Ok, it works. Now we can improve this code by removing code repetitions in html and controller.

Let's store appNames in array `appNames`. You can hardcode it

```
$scope.appNames = ["App X", "App Y", "App Z"];
```

or retrieve it dinamically from `tableData`

```
$scope.appNames = Array.from(new Set($scope.tableData.map(a => a.appName)));
```

We will need structure to store info if row for given app name should be expanded. Lets create map `expanding` and set `false` value for each app name as a key.

```
$scope.expanding = {};
for (index = 0; index < $scope.appNames.length; index++) {
  $scope.expanding[$scope.appNames[index]] = false;
 }
```

Now we can have html without repetiotions:

```
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="name in appNames">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="10" ng-click=swapExpanding(name)>{{name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="expanding[name]" ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: { appName: name}">
        <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
        ...
        <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and simple swapping function:

```
$scope.swapExpanding = function(name) {
  $scope.expanding[name] = !$scope.expanding[name];
}
```

See how it works in snippet below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.tableData = [{
      "appName": "App X",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.25",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App X",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App X",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.23",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Y",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.1",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Y",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.2",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Z",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.0",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    },
    {
      "appName": "App Z",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.1",
      "blocker": "3",
      "critical": "4",
      "major": "30",
      "minor": "2",
      "UnitTestsTotal": "59",
      "FailedTests": "0",
      "CodeCoverage": "90"
    }
  ]

  $scope.appNames = Array.from(new Set($scope.tableData.map(a => a.appName)));;

  $scope.expanding = {};
  for (index = 0; index < $scope.appNames.length; index++) {
    $scope.expanding[$scope.appNames[index]] = false;
  }

  $scope.swapExpanding = function(name) {
    $scope.expanding[name] = !$scope.expanding[name];
  }

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="name in appNames">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="10" ng-click=swapExpanding(name)>{{name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="expanding[name]" ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: { appName: name}">
        <td>{{item.appName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.GitTag}}</td>
        <td>{{item.blocker}}</td>
        <td>{{item.critical}}</td>
        <td>{{item.major}}</td>
        <td>{{item.minor}}</td>
        <td>{{item.UnitTestsTotal}}</td>
        <td>{{item.FailedTests}}</td>
        <td>{{item.CodeCoverage}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Worked like a charm!